# Identifying relationships create too many keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a working database where I've used only non-identifying relationships except many-to-many connections. I had to make changes to it anyway so I figured I will improve it on the way; I've just read about the difference between non- and identifying relationships and I've learned that the latter should be used where a child can't exist without a parent. And, for example, I have table of 'Meetings' which is basically a set of 'Votings' with some common values - lonely 'Meeting' has no right to be so I was just using cascade delete on non-identifying relationship, but now I've joined them with use of identifying one. So I did, with some other tables; obviouslynot all of them, but not I've ended up with this table of 'Results' which has... 11 primary keys and one foreign key! There were just three foreign keys before the changes. It really only helps with management if I don't have to go back all the way, table by table, to get to the root, but there will be like thousands of records there and I was wondering if it will have some real impact on performance or size of the database. Is it the way to go or not? For me, it just looks weird when simple connecting table has so much data in it... 
[image: The database looks like this now.]

'Results' table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deputydb`.`Result` (
  `Options_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_legalNumberSets_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_HeadingsForVotings_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_Meetings_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_Meetings_Venues_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_Meetings_Venues_Settings_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Options_Votings_Meetings_HeadingsForMeetings_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Microphones_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Microphones_Venues_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Microphones_Venues_Settings_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `People_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Options_id`, `Options_Votings_id`, `Options_Votings_legalNumberSets_id`, `Options_Votings_HeadingsForVotings_id`, `Options_Votings_Meetings_id`, `Options_Votings_Meetings_Venues_id`, `Options_Votings_Meetings_Venues_Settings_id`, `Options_Votings_Meetings_HeadingsForMeetings_id`, `Microphones_id`, `Microphones_Venues_id`, `Microphones_Venues_Settings_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Result_Microphones1_idx` (`Microphones_id` ASC, `Microphones_Venues_id` ASC, `Microphones_Venues_Settings_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Result_People1_idx` (`People_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Result_Options1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Options_id` , `Options_Votings_id` , `Options_Votings_legalNumberSets_id` , `Options_Votings_HeadingsForVotings_id` , `Options_Votings_Meetings_id` , `Options_Votings_Meetings_Venues_id` , `Options_Votings_Meetings_Venues_Settings_id` , `Options_Votings_Meetings_HeadingsForMeetings_id`)
    REFERENCES `deputydb`.`Options` (`id` , `Votings_id` , `Votings_legalNumberSets_id` , `Votings_HeadingsForVotings_id` , `Votings_Meetings_id` , `Votings_Meetings_Venues_id` , `Votings_Meetings_Venues_Settings_id` , `Votings_Meetings_HeadingsForMeetings_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Result_Microphones1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Microphones_id` , `Microphones_Venues_id` , `Microphones_Venues_Settings_id`)
    REFERENCES `deputydb`.`Microphones` (`id` , `Venues_id` , `Venues_Settings_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Result_People1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`People_id`)
    REFERENCES `deputydb`.`People` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: "which has... 11 primary keys" I understand what you are saying, but sounds very wrong. Use better a "composite primary key with 11 fields".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Improvement" is something that depends on the context. From the pure formal point of view, you may be right (assuming it is really a weak entity and your fields are correct). However, after design, normalization and application of all the good design patterns comes the truth about computer limitations and its implementations.

In particular, in InnoDB, for that table, **you will get 3 secondary indexes which each of them will store the full contents of the primary key values, resulting in a table 3 times larger** (and potentially many times as slower) than the version without the big PK. Of course, if you plan to store just some few records it won't be a problem, but with only a few thousand the difference can be huge.

Using a pseudokey as the primary key will be reasonable in this case from the implementation perspective and a common practice, be it the "good design" or not. It is the same reason why sometimes we prefer to use numeric auto increment keys for PKs instead of reusing an already existent unique string. Most design flaws are then solved by implementing extra logic in the application or a middle tier, which provide better scalability and features than MySQL.

Comment: I won't use pseudokey as my application doesn't work on database all the time... it downloads all the data and then uploads the changes. So in the meantime it needs to give some id values to the items. And you are right - if it's managing the database by itself, there is no point to test MySQL engines. I just thought it will simplyfy future changes.

Answer (score 0):

This DB schema is a nightmare... 
I don't use this tool. BUT...

I'am guessing that You have click on each relation in GUI (meant as line between tables)
and set for EACH dependent table proper PARENT KEY.